# Unit testing instance of an Iterable

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am developing a Junit 4 test case (black box) for the following method:

```
/**
* Returns all points in the symbol table.
*/
public Iterable<Point2D> points();
```

The method is supposed to return all points inside the KdTree symbol table. I *don't* make any assumptions regarding a particular implementation of an Iterable being returned from the method, therefore I develop the following unit test:

```
@Test
public void emptySTPointsTest() {
    KdTreeST<Integer> kd = new KdTreeST<>();      // initializing empty ST
    Iterable<Point2D> pts = kd.points();      // arbitrary decision

    assertFalse(pts.iterator().hasNext());        // ?!
}
```

Are there other ways to check if the instance of an Iterable is (not) empty? What is the *"right" (or most common) way*  of implementing these kinds of unit tests, when you can't explicitly check number of elements and you don't know which order they come in (not just empty case, but in general)?

P.S I have tried to utilize Hamcrest's Matchers, however Iterable interface doesn't specify `size()` method, so I guess it wouldn't be that useful in this case.

**Edit**: Instead of 
`Iterable<Point2D> pts = new HashSet<>();`
I should have written `Iterable<Point2D> pts = kd.points();`

Comment: what is the sense of black box unit test in this case?

Comment: @Lashane I was trying to say that I don't know beforehand which implementation of Iterable is being returned: I can't inspect the method, the _only thing_ I have is a spec for the method.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your method is fine; there's nothing wrong with it.</strike> As the other answer points out, you're testing the iterator you got from the HashSet and not from the `KdTreeST`.

Also, there is a Hamcrest Matcher for your situation.

```
assertThat(pts.iterator(), is(emptyIterable()));
```

(assuming you statically import from `org.hamcrest.Matchers`)

Answer (score 0):

The unit test that you've written is unit-testing the HashSet class (in particular, the behavior of `HashSet#iterator()` when the set is empty). It's not testing your `points` method.

To answer your question about empty Iterables, however... it looks like that's certainly one way to test for an empty Iterable. The [Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface only has one method: `iterator`.

Perhaps declaring `points` to return an `Iterable` is a bit too abstract for your needs. Why not bump it up to `Collection<Point2D>`? This way, you can use [Collection#isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#isEmpty()), which is easier to read.

Comment: You are right, somehow I overlooked that I was in fact testing instance of the `HashSet` instead of calling `points()` method. Thanks.